# php - склейка двух массивов

Tags: php

Есть два массива: `$images` и `$count`, нужно создать один массив где в нем такая архитектура

```
$Arr(
[0] -> Arr([0] -> $images = 'mda.jpg', [1] -> $count = '5')
[1] -> Arr([0] -> $images = 'takoe.jpg', [1] -> $count = '6')
)
```

Comment: Такой архитектуры в массивах быть не может.

Comment: Пожалуйста, в вопросе явно укажите примерную структуру массивов `$images` и `$count`: ключи и значения. И какой результирующий массив хотите получить. Примеры как это выглядит можете посмотреть в документации — [Массивы](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php). Обратите внимание на [синтаксис языка программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Синтаксис_(программирование)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно склеить элемент с индексом 0 с элементом другого массива с аналогичным ключем, воспользуйтесь чем-то наподобие этого:

```
for ($i = 0, $i<count($images), $i++) {
    $result [] = [images[$i], $count[$i]];
}
```